# Chomsky Classification of Languages

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, chomsky-hierarchy

Given is a language $A = \{ a^n\:b\:c^{2n}\:b^m |\; n ∈ N^{+} ;\; m ∈ N \}$ ; where $N^{+}$ are the natural numbers excluding 0.

I have found a type-1 grammar to describe it:

$S \to A_1A_2$

$A_1 \to aA_1cc \;| \; abcc$

$A2 \to bA_2 \; |\; \epsilon$

However, this doesn't tell me much about the language's Chomsky type. How can I know if there exists a more restricted grammar and how can I find it?

Comment: The most restricted grammar for $A$ is [type-2 grammar, the context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#Type-2_grammars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language $A = \{ a^n\:b\:c^{2n}\:b^m |\; n ∈ N^{+} ;\; m ∈ N \}$ is not obviously regular since finite automata do not have memory and hence it is not possible for them to determine the relation between $a$ and $c$.

Let us try to construct a Type-2 grammar for this language. Note that Type-2 grammars are of the form  $V\to(V \cup T)^{*}$ where $V$ represents non-terminals and $T$ represents terminals. So our example would lead to something like this:

$S \to a\:A_1\:cc\:A_2 $

$A_1 \to a\:A_1\:cc\;|\;b$

$A_2 \to b\:A_2\;|\;\epsilon$

Hence we see that this is a Type-2 grammar according to the Chomsky hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you. I know that A is not regular and can prove this with the Pumping Lemma. A also is at least Type-1. How can I be certain that there doesn't exist a Type-2 grammar to describe it?